# MPMoviePlayerViewController seems to have a memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to make a moviePlayer.  But, when I click the "done" button, or cancel the player, the memory used always increases.  Why??

Comment: Not so sure, but it may be an autorelease, you need to do something else to start the next UI cycle loop and it will release the MPMoviePlayerVC